bash: Redirecting to multiple file descriptors
Have read the bash manual on duplicating file descriptors
Is there a way to redirect to multiple file descriptors. Say to both stdout and stderr. Like this?
echo "hello" >&1 >&2

This does work in zsh:
zsh -c 'echo "hello" >&1 >&2'

Is there a way to do this in bash?

Please don't add tae [tag:zsh] tag to Bash questions. You're not adding [tag:tcsh] or [tag:powershell] either.

Use tee to split the output to multiple destinations. Then you can use /dev/stderr make one of them stderr (it writes to stdout by default).
echo "hello" | tee /dev/stderr

More generally you can use /dev/fd/N to write to file descriptor N.

1. Using tee:
echo "hello" | tee /dev/fd/2

This outputs to both stderr(/dev/fd/2) & stdout(1).
This can take multiple arguments or be chained further to send output to multiple file descriptors. Thanks @Barmar
echo "hello" | tee /dev/fd/2 /dev/fd/N

echo "hello" | tee /dev/fd/2 | tee /dev/fd/N

Issues:

Doesn't seem work in scripts, in some situations (running as a pm2 process, started by systemd). See why


2. Using tee with cat:
A hacky method for scripting, using a tmp file:
TEMP="${TEMP:=$(mktemp)}"; echo "hello" | tee "${TEMP}"; cat "$TEMP" >&2;

This outputs to tmp file & stdout, and reads tmp file to stderr.
Learning from here, this hack can be simplified using a cat sub-process:

echo hello | tee -- >(cat >&2)



Do note that bash doesn't wait for that cat process [to return].


Where >(cat >&2) expands to a /dev/fd/n (or /proc/self/fd/n which is the same on Linux), but n is a fd open on a pipe here, and what you feed to that pipe is read by cat, and what cat reads from that pipe it writes on stderr.


Why doesn't it work in scripts?

@Barmar Was running it pm2, I get tee: /dev/fd/2: No such device or address. Not sure why....

Are you sure the script is running with bash, not sh? If the OS doesn't provide /dev/fd, bash emulates it, but sh doesn't.

@Barmar I tried determining shell from the script using readlink -f /proc/$$/exe and ps -o args= -p "$$". Both say it is running in bash.

There's no need to pipe multiple calls to tee. You can give tee multiple filename arguments and it will split to all of them.

I put your code in a file and then did bash filename and it worked fine. I tried on both Debian Linux and MacOS. I don't know why you get an error. Note that if I change it to /dev/fd/3 I get No such file or directory, not the error you got. Something strange is going on.

Perhaps you could ask a question on [linux.se] to find out why you're getting that error.

@Barmar Thanks, have asked here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/782430/bash-script-running-in-pm2-unable-to-access-file-descriptors-files-at-dev-fd
